# dataLayer.push duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push the dataLayer. But it keeps giving me a duplicate array. Please see below my code

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script>

 dataLayer = [{
 'productID': '123456',
 'productTitle': 'Very awesome product',
 'productPrice': '13.00'
 }];
function next_step1c() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'Enquiry',
     'PageURL': window.location.href,

     });
}
</script>
<fieldset id="firstc">
          <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-success" onclick="next_step1c()">
                <input type="radio" name="buy" id="check1c" value="Rolex"/>
                <label for="check1c">Rolex</label>
            </div>
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I click the radio button I get the below result.
[image]

But when I clicked the word **Rolex**. I am getting duplicate

[image]

How can I get one push only when I clicked the word **Rolex**?

Answer (score 2):

try like this.
You added onclick to `.funkyradio-success` class. SO when you `clicked` the radio button it works only `1` time. But when You clicked to label button, there it `clicks` `double`. Because when you `click label` there works `.funkyradio-success` onclick. And `label binded to radio input` so `input click trigger` works too. So your function calls `2` times.

```js
 dataLayer = [{
 'productID': '123456',
 'productTitle': 'Very awesome product',
 'productPrice': '13.00'
 }];
function next_step1c() {
console.log('you clicked me');
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'Enquiry',
     'PageURL': window.location.href,

     });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<fieldset id="firstc">
          <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-success" onclick="next_step1c()">
                <input type="radio" name="buy" id="check1c" value="Rolex"/>
                <label for="check1c">Rolex</label>
            </div>
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

Add onclick to input radio

```js
 dataLayer = [{
 'productID': '123456',
 'productTitle': 'Very awesome product',
 'productPrice': '13.00'
 }];
function next_step1c() {
console.log('you clicked me');
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'Enquiry',
     'PageURL': window.location.href,

     });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>

<fieldset id="firstc">
          <div class="funkyradio">
            <div class="funkyradio-success" >
                <input type="radio" name="buy" id="check1c" onclick="next_step1c()" value="Rolex"/>
                <label for="check1c">Rolex</label>
            </div>
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.onchange` instead for the radio type input element, and I see no purpose for checking if that dataLayer is defined cause it will always be in this code, and avoid writing inline JS cause it has lot of disadvantages.

```js
var dataLayer = [{
 'productID': '123456',
 'productTitle': 'Very awesome product',
 'productPrice': '13.00'
}];

document.querySelector("#check1c").onchange = function () {
  dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'Enquiry',
   'PageURL': window.location.href,
  });
  console.log(dataLayer);
};
```

```html
<fieldset id="firstc">
  <div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-success">
        <input type="radio" name="buy" id="check1c" value="Rolex"/>
        <label for="check1c">Rolex</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```